# Nested FormGroup resets all groups

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have a FormGroup with nested groups:

```
this.addComponentForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        'initialValues': this.fb.group({...this.initialFormValues, ...this.dynamicFormValues, ...this.phaseFormValues}),
        'dynamicValues': this.fb.group({...this.dynamicFormValues})
      }
```

To get the nested groups (per the docs):

```
  get initialValues(): any { return this.addComponentForm.get('initialValues'); }
  get dynamicValues(): any { return this.addComponentForm.get('dynamicValues'); }
```

All this works fine thus far, forms build, no errors. I have an action that need to only clear the `initialValues` formgroup: `this.initialValues.reset();` However, the data in `this.dynamicValues` is also getting set to null. Commenting out the reset clears nothing so I know this is where things are getting cleared in both groups.

I tried `this.initialValues.reset({onlySelf: true});` but nope.

Comment: Your code should do exactly what you want to achieve. Could you please provide the html?

Comment: I think that because you are referencing `dynamicFormValues` in `'initialValues': this.fb.group({...this.initialFormValues, ...this.dynamicFormValues,`

Comment: `this.dynamicFormValues` is used in both formGroups referencing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear. You're using the spread operator to copy the dynamicValues into initialValues.